# rule generalization-NCA algebra

Tags: function-construction, syntax, algebra, ncalgebra

How can I generalize the rule

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMulitply]

l___ ** (Times[x1__, y__NonCommutativeMultiply] + Times[x2__, z__NonCommutativeMultiply]) ** r___   := x1 l ** y ** r + x2 l ** z ** r

 Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply]
```

to include infinite terms?

`Distribute` does it but I don't want to use it.

Comment: "... but I don't want to use it" - Why?

Comment: Can you give an example of what is not working?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Please see [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238138/parallel-evaluation-produces-wrong-result). I posted the problem as a new question

Comment: @MarcoB Please see [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238138/parallel-evaluation-produces-wrong-result). I posted the problem as a new question