# Parallel evaluation produces wrong result

Tags: function-construction, syntax, parallelization

Consider the following code:

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];

ClearAll[NonCommutativeMultiply]

NonCommutativeMultiply[] := 1
NonCommutativeMultiply[l___, 0, r___] := 0
NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, 1, b___] := a ** b
NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, Times[-1, b_], c___] := -a ** b ** c
NonCommutativeMultiply[a_] := a


SetAttributes[NonCommutativeMultiply, {OneIdentity, Flat}]

Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];

Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];


left___ ** HoldPattern[Times[z_, p : (a[x_] | ad[x_])]] ** right___ := z*left ** p ** right
left___ ** HoldPattern[Times[u_[x_], p : (a[x_] | ad[x_])]] ** right___ := u[x]*left ** p ** right
left___ ** HoldPattern[Times[z__, p : (a[x_] | ad[x_])]] ** right___ :=z*left ** p ** right
left___ ** Times[z___, y__NonCommutativeMultiply, x___] ** right___ := z*x*left ** y ** right

x___ ** y__Real ** z___ := y x ** z
x___ ** y__Integer ** z___ := y x ** z
l___ ** y__Power ** r___ := y l ** r
l___ ** Times[x__, y__] ** r___ := Times[x, y] l ** r

a[x_] ** a[x_] := 1
ad[x_] ** ad[x_] := 1

Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];

xval[x___] := NonCommutativeMultiply[x];

xval[] := 1
xval[___ ** 0 ** ___] := 0

xval[x__Plus] := Map[ExpVal, x]   

xval[Times[x__, y_NonCommutativeMultiply, z___]] := x z ExpVal[y]  
xval[Times[x___, y_NonCommutativeMultiply, z__]] := x z ExpVal[y]
xval[___ ** a[x_]] := 0;
```

Now let's evaluate the matrix whose elements are given by: $ad(i)**\Big(2 |\cos(\pi i)| ad(j)**a(j)+2 |\sin(\pi j/2)|ad(j)**a(j)\Big)**a(i)$:

```
sind = 10;
Clear[f, i, j]
f[i_, j_] := xval[Distribute[ad[i] ** (2 Abs[Cos[Pi i]] ad[j] ** a[j] + 2 Abs[Sin[Pi j/2]] ad[j] ** a[j]) ** a[i]]]
mat = Array[f, {sind, sind}];
mat
```

The output is the diagonal matrix:

```
{{4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}}
```

So far so good. Now let's try to compute the same matrix using parallel features. I try:

```
Clear[fp, i, j, matp]
LaunchKernels[2]
fp[i_, j_] := xval[Distribute[ad[i] ** (2 Abs[Cos[Pi i]] ad[j] ** a[j] + 2 Abs[Sin[Pi j/2]] ad[j] ** a[j]) ** a[i]]]
matp = ParallelArray[fp, {sind, sind}, DistributedContexts -> Automatic];
MatrixForm[matp]
```

The output is the zero matrix, which is wrong

Let's try:

```
LaunchKernels[2]
Parallelize[Table[f[i, j], {i, 1, sind}, {j, 1, sind}]]
```

The output is again the zero matrix.

As I see it the problem is that I don't use the `ParallelArray` or `Parallelize` properly. What am I doing wrong?

MMA's manual states " Functions defined interactively can immediately be used in parallel"

**EDIT**

Based on the answer by @Sjoerd Smit let's check the following:

```
Quiet@LaunchKernels[];
DistributeDefinitions[NonCommutativeMultiply, xval]; (* can be omitted *)
ParallelEvaluate[a[x] ** a[x]]
ParallelEvaluate[Distribute[ad[1] ** (2 Abs[Cos[Pi 1]] ad[1] ** a[1] + 2 Abs[Sin[Pi 1/2]] ad[1] ** a[1]) ** a[1]]]
ParallelEvaluate[xval[Distribute[ad[1] ** (2 Abs[Cos[Pi 1]] ad[1] ** a[1]+ 2 Abs[Sin[Pi 1/2]] ad[1] ** a[1]) ** a[1]]]]
ParallelEvaluate[xval[a[x] ** a[x]]]

(* output *)
{1, 1, 1, 1}  (* correct *)
{4, 4, 4, 4}  (* correct *)
{0, 0, 0, 0}  (* WRONG *)
{0, 0, 0, 0}  (* WRONG *)
```

which suggests that `xval` does not work properly in parallel.
Specifically, `ParallelEvaluate[xval[a[x] ** a[x]]]` gives `0` in all kernels which shows that `xval` doesn't recognize that `a[x]**a[x]==1` when it works in parallel. I can't see the reason though

Comment: You might want to either use explicit `Print`, or `Trace`, to see where it goes wrong in the parallel case.

Comment: This obviously needs running code to troubleshoot, but you did not include the definitions of `sind` and `ExpVal`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the definitions for `NonCommutativeMultiply` don't make it to the parallel kernels. You can test this as follows:

```
CloseKernels[];
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
NonCommutativeMultiply[args___] := f[args];
Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
Quiet @ LaunchKernels[];
DistributeDefinitions[NonCommutativeMultiply];
ParallelEvaluate[Hold[Evaluate[3 ** 2]], DistributedContexts -> Automatic]
```

> {Hold[3 ** 2], Hold[3 ** 2], Hold[3 ** 2], Hold[3 ** 2]}

The `Hold[Evaluate[...]]` trick is very useful for figuring out if something evaluates on the parallel kernels or only on the main kernel. If you'd just use

```
ParallelEvaluate[3 ** 2, DistributedContexts -> Automatic]
```

> {f[3, 2], f[3, 2], f[3, 2], f[3, 2]}

it looks like it works because the main kernel applies the definition of `NonCommutativeMultiply`.

I suspect that the `Protected` attribute is interfering with the distribution of the definitions. You can do this instead to circumvent the problem:

```
CloseKernels[];
Quiet @ LaunchKernels[];
ParallelEvaluate[
  Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
  NonCommutativeMultiply[args___] := f[args];
  Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply]
];
ParallelEvaluate[Hold[Evaluate[3 ** 2]]]
```

> {Hold[f[3, 2]], Hold[f[3, 2]], Hold[f[3, 2]], Hold[f[3, 2]]}

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think `NonCommutativeMultiply` is the problem. Consider `g[i_, j_] := Distribute[ad[i] ** (2 Abs[Cos[Pi i]] ad[j] ** a[j] + 2 Abs[Sin[Pi j/2]] ad[j] **a[j]) ** a[i]]
s1=Sum[g[i, j], {i, sind}, {j, sind}]` Then evaluate the sum parallel `LaunchKernels[4];
s2 = ParallelSum[g[i, j], {i, sind}, {j, sind}] ` You see that `s1==s2` I think something goes wrong with `xval` in parallel

Comment: Fair point. I recommend you try all the functions you defined in isolation using the `Hold[Evaluate[...]]` trick to see which functions are behaving differently when evaluated in parallel. Or try putting all of your definitions inside of `ParallelEvaluate` like I did to make sure the definitions land on the kernels correctly.